# Recursively walking a DAG in an SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a graph which consists of two types of nodes `Task` and `Subtask`. Lists of these are stored along with metadata (for now, we can just assume a single metadata string column called "name") in two tables `TaskTable` and `SubTaskTable`. `Task`s will have subtasks under them which will be connected in the form of a DAG. A `Task` `A` might have 5 subtasks `st1`, `st2`, `st3`, `st4`, and `st5` which are connected like so

[image]

This is represented in the database like so in a `dependencies` table.

```
| for_task | from_subtask | to_subtask |
|----------+--------------+------------|
| A        |            1 |          2 |
| A        |            1 |          3 |
| A        |            2 |          4 |
| A        |            3 |          4 |
| A        |            4 |          5 |
```

So far so, good. However, now, there is a possibility that another task `B` will have a similar DAG for its own subtasks which is okay too.

The third requirement is that a `Task` should be able to have another `Task` as a dependency and there should be some way to "expand" the subtask tree when I take the top level task. For example,

[image]

And `B` itself has subtasks like so

[image]

I've changed my `dependencies` table to hold this information as well like so

```
| for_task | from_task | from_subtask | to_task | to_subtask |
|----------+-----------+--------------+---------+------------|
| A        |           |            1 |         |          2 |
| A        |           |            1 |         |          3 |
| A        |           |            2 |         |          4 |
| A        |           |            3 |         |          4 |
| A        |           |            4 |         |          5 |
| A        |           |            1 | B       |            |
| B        |           |            6 |         |          7 |
| B        |           |            6 |         |          8 |
| B        |           |            7 |         |          8 |
| B        |           |            8 |         |          9 |
```

I have two questions

1. Is this a good way to store this kind of information?
2. How would I construct a query that will give "expand" the task `B` when I get all the tasks for task `A` and give me the whole list of subtasks.

For 2, I'd expect something like this

```
| from_task | to_task |
|-----------+---------|
|         1 |       2 |
|         1 |       3 |
|         2 |       4 |
|         3 |       4 |
|         4 |       5 |
|         1 |       6 |The subtask here is directly linked to the subtask of B
|         6 |       7 |
|         6 |       8 |
|         7 |       8 |
|         8 |       9 |
```

No more tasks. Just a tree of subtasks.

This is using postgreSQL if that's relevant.

Comment: Can you share the query result you would expect for your question 2 ?

Comment: Your description is ambiguous.  The main problem seems to be around the Task to Task association.  In your "third requirement", you describe a Task to Task dependency requirement, regardless of subtasks associated with each.  That should probably be in a separate graph/list, not mixed in with subtasks.  Can you clarify that in your question?

Comment: or just link st1 to st6 directly.  It's not clear why we want to link tasks.  The picture that links (st1) to [B] could just link (st1) to (st6) and we can then remove the to_task column.

Comment: @JonArmstrong The thing is that `Task`s will be created with dependencies of subtasks and stored in the system. Imagine that a `Task` is something like "upgrade database". It will have a series of sub tasks (e.g. shutdown db, upgrade software, migrate, perform tetsts etc.) and this is available now as a single `Task` which other `Task`s can just directly use (e.g. a system upgrade `Task` might have an "Upgrade database" task as one of it's steps.). When that happens, it shouldn't have the dependent Task itself but just its subtasks.

Comment: Probably missing something, but why do you find it necessary to store anything more complex than a task-dep pairs?  A-st5, st5-st4, st4-st2, st4-st3.  Then use a CTE, that’s postgres way I’d navigate graphs.  If A is “a special task” store that elsewhere, not in the hierarchy table which should only hold things like edge weights (say task context switching costs).  I.e. this from/to stuff in multiple columns has a bad code/table structure smell to me.

Comment: @JLPeyret It's more of a domain thing. The "Task" level entities will be created by users and shared. They'll show up in lists on the app etc. It should be possible to compose new tasks using existing ones (and perhaps by adding a few subtasks). So, while the relationships need to be maintained, they have to be "serialised" into a tree of only subtasks during execution. I agree about the from/to smell which is why I posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

Instinctively, I would create a first table `task` which describes every tasks independently (also including maybe the subtasks to be decided) :

```
CREATE TABLE task 
( name text PRIMARY KEY -- can add hereafter any kind of task attributes as new columns
) ;
```

Then I would keep your first table `dependencies` renamed as `subtask_dependency` with only 3 columns and add a foreign key to `task` :

```
CREATE TABLE subtask_dependency
( for_task text
, from_subtask text
, to_subtask text
, CONSTRAINT pk_subtask PRIMARY KEY (for_task, from_subtask, to_subtask)
, CONSTRAINT fk_task FOREIGN KEY (for_task) REFERENCES task (name)
  MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ;
```

and I would create a second table `task_dependency` the same way :

```
CREATE TABLE task_dependency
( from_task text
, from_subtask text
, to_task text
, to_subtask text -- this column is not mandatory but it is helpful to store the root subtask of to_task
, CONSTRAINT pk_task PRIMARY KEY (from_task, from_subtask, to_task)
, CONSTRAINT fk_fromtask FOREIGN KEY (from_task) REFERENCES task (name)
  MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
, CONSTRAINT fk_totask FOREIGN KEY (to_task) REFERENCES task (name)
  MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ;
```

Then the query to get your expected result with only one level of nested task :

```
SELECT from_subtask, to_subtask
  FROM subtask_dependency AS s
 WHERE for_task = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT from_subtask, to_subtask
 FROM task_dependency
 WHERE from_task = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT s.from_subtask, s.to_subtask
  FROM subtask_dependency AS s
  LEFT JOIN task_dependency AS t
    ON t.to_task = s.for_task
 WHERE t.from_task = 'A'
```

And more generally, the query to get your expected result with multi level nested tasks :

```
WITH RECURSIVE list (from_task, from_subtask, to_task, to_subtask) AS
( SELECT NULL, NULL, from_task, from_subtask
    FROM task_dependency
   WHERE from_task = 'A'
 UNION ALL
  SELECT t.from_task, t.from_subtask, t.to_task, t.to_subtask
    FROM list AS l
   INNER JOIN task_dependency AS t
      ON t.from_task = l.to_task
     AND t.from_subtask = l.to_subtask
)
SELECT s.from_subtask, s.to_subtask
  FROM list AS l
 INNER JOIN subtask_dependency AS s
    ON s.for_task = l.to_task
UNION ALL
SELECT l.from_subtask, l.to_subtask
  FROM list AS l
 WHERE l.from_subtask IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0tPlXyLY)